# Enviar un dato de tipo carácter a un Nodo. Java

Tags: java, poo, estructuras

Estoy haciendo un programa para crear un árbol binario en Java el cual recibe un vector de caracteres como datos para los nodos, sin embargo cuando lo ejecuto en el punto exacto en que se le envía el dato al nodo me arroja un error el cuál no he podido solventar. Es importante aclarar que definí en la clase nodo que el dato es de tipo char.

```
public void create(char[] vc) {
        Nodo p;`
        int i = 0;
        p = punta;
        while (i < vc.length) {
            if (p == null) {
                p.setDato(vc[i]); //En este punto me arroja el error
            } else if (vc[i] < p.getDato() && p.getLi() != null) {
                Nodo x = new Nodo();
                x.setDato(vc[i]);
                p.setLi(x);
            } else if (vc[i] > p.getDato() && p.getLd() != null) {
                Nodo x = new Nodo();
                x.setDato(vc[i]);
                p.setLd(x);
            }
            i++;
        }
```

Esté es el código de mi clase nodo

```
package binarytrees;


public class Nodo {
    
    private char Dato;
    private Nodo Ld, Li;

    //Constructor
    public Nodo(char Dato, Nodo Ld, Nodo Li) {
        this.Dato = Dato;
        Ld = null;
        Li = null;
    }
    
    public Nodo(){
        
    }

    public int getDato() {
        return Dato;
    }

    public void setDato(char Dato) {
        this.Dato = Dato;
    }

    public Nodo getLd() {
        return Ld;
    }

    public void setLd(Nodo Ld) {
        this.Ld = Ld;
    }

    public Nodo getLi() {
        return Li;
    }

    public void setLi(Nodo Li) {
        this.Li = Li;
    }
}
```

Y este es el error que me sale

![1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QbDOZ.png

Comment: ¿Cuál es el código de tu clase nodo? ¿Cuál es el error que te sale?

Comment: Hola, acabo de agregar esta información en mi pregunta. Gracias

Comment: El error es obvio. La condición que tienes es `p == null`. Si `p` es nulo, no es posible hacer ninguna asignación o acción con dicha variable. Deberías inicializar el nodo en lugar de tratar de hacer el `set` del dato. En lugar de esa línea deberías hacer `p = new Nodo(vc[i], null, null);`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error que te esta dando, es por que estas validando que P es null, pero tratas de asignar valore a sus atributos.

Puedes tratar con el cambio que te agregue.

```
public void create(char[] vc) {
        Nodo p;`
        int i = 0;
        p = punta;
        while (i < vc.length) {
            if (p == null) {
                p = new Nodo(); // Inicializas la variable P
                p.setDato(vc[i]); //En este punto me arroja el error
            } else if (vc[i] < p.getDato() && p.getLi() != null) {
                Nodo x = new Nodo();
                x.setDato(vc[i]);
                p.setLi(x);
            } else if (vc[i] > p.getDato() && p.getLd() != null) {
                Nodo x = new Nodo();
                x.setDato(vc[i]);
                p.setLd(x);
            }
            i++;
        }
```

Israel Ramos